# Factory Pattern when one object can't implement the full interface and the Interface Segregation Principle

Tags: python, design-patterns, factory, solid-principles

I am refactoring a code and my intention is to use the Factory Design Pattern for object creation. I am also learning about SOLID principles and trying to apply them on the go.
My problem is that not all objects created by the factory implement all the methods of the interface but most of them.

**Description of the application:**
There are three discount classes for three different materials (gold, silver and platinum). All three have a regular discount but only silver and gold have a bonus discount.

**Solution 1:** Same interface but breaking the Interface Segregation Principle

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Discount(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def regularDiscount(self):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def bonusDiscount(self):
        ...


class SilverDiscount(Discount):
    def regularDiscount(self, price):
        return price - 20

    def bonusDiscount(self, price):
        return price * 0.98


class GoldDiscount(Discount):
    def regularDiscount(self, price):
        return price - 50

    def bonusDiscount(self, price):
        return price * 0.95


class PlatinumDiscount(Discount):
    def regularDiscount(self, price):
        return price - 20

    # Unnecesarily implemented method because platinum doesn't have bonus discount
    def bonusDiscount(self, price):
        return price


def DiscountFactory(material: str ="gold") -> Discount:
    discounts = {
        "gold": GoldDiscount,
        "silver": SilverDiscount,
        "platinum": PlatinumDiscount
    }
    return discounts[material]()
```

**Solution 2:** Two different interfaces but don't know what is the return type for the Factory

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class RegularDiscount(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def regularDiscount(self):
        ...


class BonusDiscount(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def bonusDiscount(self):
        ...

    
class SilverDiscount(RegularDiscount, BonusDiscount):
    def regularDiscount(self, price):
        return price - 20

    def bonusDiscount(self, price):
        return price * 0.98


class GoldDiscount(RegularDiscount, BonusDiscount):
    def regularDiscount(self, price):
        return price - 50

    def bonusDiscount(self, price):
        return price * 0.95


class PlatinumDiscount(RegularDiscount):
    def regularDiscount(self, price):
        return price - 20

# What return type to use?
def DiscountFactory(material: str ="gold") -> ?????????:
    discounts = {
        "gold": GoldDiscount,
        "silver": SilverDiscount,
        "platinum": PlatinumDiscount
    }
    return discounts[material]()
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: What does it mean that platinum doesn't have a bonus discount? Are you expecting the code that calls `bonusDiscount` to somehow know that a given discount class doesn't support it?

Comment: I wouldn't like to but in solution 2 I'd have to. I can set a `Union` return type for the factory and in the calling code use `isinstance` to know if it supports the bonus discount or not. That is why I prefer the first solution, it yields a much cleaner code for the calling part but as it turned out it violates the Interface Segregation Principle. So I am basically confused since to my perspective the solution 1 seems to be better.

Comment: Yes, solution 1 is better; and I don't think it violates the Interface Segregation Principle. It makes perfect sense for `PlatinumDiscount` to handle knowing that its bonus discount is zero, rather than expecting clients to figure that out on their own. (In fact, you mat also need a `NoDiscount` class, whose regular discount and bonus discount are *both* zero.)

Comment: You're doing things backward.  IF you need to create objects of a particular type, AND you want to off-load the dependencies of the creation process via DI, THEN you decide to use a factory.  You can't have a requirement for a factory without knowing what that "particular type" is.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've been thinking about your question over the past day or so, and trying to understand where it's coming from; and I've come to the conclusion that you have a misconception about the Interface Segregation Principle.

(Note: I should mention that there's no single correct interpretation of the SOLID principles; different people mean different things by them, and interpret them differently over time. So I can't give you an authoritative explanation of what the Interface Segregation Principle means. But I think you have a specific misconception that I *can* address.)

Consider the phrasing from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle:

> […] no code should be forced to depend on methods it does not use. […] clients will only have to know about the methods that are of interest to them.

If I'm understanding your question and comments correctly, you feel that your solution #1 violates this principle because the `PlatinumDiscount` class has to implement a "method[] it does not use" — one that is *not* "of interest to" it. Do I have that right?

But that's *not* what the Interface Segregation Principle is about; that principle isn't about *implementers* having to *implement* methods they don't care about, it's about *callers* having to *see* (≈ compile against) methods they don't care about.

Suppose I have a logging framework, with a 'log' method for writing out a log-message and a 'configure' method for configuring the framework. There might be hundreds of classes in my application that need to call the 'log' method; but only one or two that need to call 'configure'. So the Interface Segregation Principle argues that there should be an interface that exposes only the 'log' method.

In your case, the clients of `Discount` *do* care about both `regularDiscount` and `bonusDiscount`, because they sometimes need to calculate regular discounts and sometimes need to calculate bonus discounts. So it's `PlatinumDiscount`'s responsibility to support those clients in cases where the material is platinum. And in your solution #1, it does that perfectly. So this doesn't violate the interface segregation principle, because the interface segregation principle doesn't care about what `PlatinumDiscount` wants.

Now, there is a principle that *does* care about what `PlatinumDiscount` wants, and that's the Single Responsibility Principle. If calculating a regular discount and calculating on a bonus discount are really two totally separate responsibilities, then sure, they shouldn't be in the same class. But in that case your solution #2 is no improvement, because that solution still forces `GoldDiscount` and `SilverDiscount` to handle both responsibilities.

But I don't think that's an issue here; it seems very reasonable to me for a single class to handle both of those things. In fact, I could even imagine getting rid of all of these classes and just having a single general-purpose method `computeDiscount(self, price, discountType, material)`; at least based on what you've shown here, that's not too broad a responsibility for one method. (The implementation would presumably make use of a dictionary held as a field.)

---

A broader point that I'd like to make is that your code should make sense. It's good to be aware of these patterns and principles because they can help you find ways to make your code make more sense (and can help you make sense of existing code that uses them), but they aren't always applicable. Never apply a design pattern unless that design pattern will make your code clearer. (Or, do apply it, as an experiment / learning experience, but then discard the change if you find that it isn't helping.) And don't let an OO principle trick you into writing worse code. That's true even if you've understood the principle perfectly.